# reading image text using google vision api

Tags: java, google-api

i am trying to read text from an image using the below code , but it is reading 400 in response.

i have saved the image in my c-drive on local computer

also i have hidden the key in the below code.

below is the function i have written to read using the vision api

```
    private static String postingtogoogle() throws Exception {
     //    Base64.encode;
    String re = "";
    String url = "https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=mykey";
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/a.png"));
    String imgstr = encodeToString(img, "png");

    imgstr = encodeToString(img, "png");

    //add reuqest header
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");

    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

    String urlParameters = "{\n"
            + "  \"requests\":[\n"
            + "    {\n"
            + "      \"image\":{\n"
            + "        \"content\":\"" + imgstr + "\"\n"
            + "      },\n"
            + "      \"features\":[\n"
            + "        {\n"
            + "          \"type\":\"LABEL_DETECTION\",\n"
            + "          \"maxResults\":1\n"
            + "        }\n"
            + "      ]\n"
            + "    }\n"
            + "  ]\n"
            + "}";

    // Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    re = response.toString();

    return re;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line:

```
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```